# Specialization of less<> works with map but not with sort

Tags: c++, stl

I have a custom class and a specialization of `less<>` for that class. I do not have any `operator<` in the class. Code looks like:

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    MyClass(int i): val(i) {}

    int val;
};

namespace std
{
    template<> struct less<MyClass>
    {
       bool operator() (const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b) const { return a.val < b.val; }
    };
}
```

Now if I create a STL map of the class as key then that works fine. But if I try to sort a vector of those objects then that gives compilation error for missing `operator<`.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It would probably be more useful to not paraphrase the error, but copy it instead. Also, create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort`, when not provided a comparator, uses `operator<` for comparisons, not `std::less`.

From the standard, [alg.sorting], the very first paragraph

> All the operations in [alg.sorting] have two versions: one that takes a function object of type Compare and one that uses an operator<.

`std::map` doesn't have two versions. It has one version, with a default template parameter which defaults to `std::less<key>`. It can't use `operator<` directly (or at least, it would be cumbersome to do so), because then the type of the comparator would actually have to be a function pointer, and the user would have to always pass a pointer to the appropriate `operator<` to the constructor. This would be a pain. By instead defaulting to the type `std::less<key>`, the map can just use a default constructed object of this type as its comparator.